# WF-1000XM3 Bad Sound during Calls on MacOS

Tags: audio

So, WF1000-XM3 works pretty fine on my Windows 10 (after A LOT of drives installation) and on Android. On MacOS it does well if NOT on a call, using AAC as the default Codec.

BUT, when I enter on a call (meet, zoom, etc...) it falls back to SCO as the codec and then the sound is awful. I tried all the download developers tools things and Enabled AAC and aptX, but still WF1000-XM3 does default to SCO making it really bad for any meeting, to the point where I just set meetings with the Laptop Mic and output sound on Wf1000 (then it uses AAC).

Sony support only mentioned that this should be on the Apple side and refer to further assist.

Has anyone seen this before?